# Delete filetable row in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I use `EntIty Framework`.In a form I bInd a view from a file table to a grid.I defined a key down event for a `grid` and when user press delete key then I call a stored procedure that delete selected row.I show photo from file table using an Image control by selectIon event on grId.

My problem is when I press delete key I must select other row of `grid` for workIng deletIng operatIon(if I do selectIon change programmatically does not any help).If I do not do this a time out exception fired from SQL for executing store procedure.
what should I do?

```
DataGrIdTextColumn BIndIng="{BIndIng CreateDatetIme}"
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by this: 'when I press delete key I must select other row of grid for workIng deletIng operatIon'. I don't understand why the subsequent row selection would affect the delete operation.

Comment: i want delete selected row from a grid in my app.delete operation in the stored procedure for deleting the row from filetable complete just when i select another row from grid in my app.if i dont do  this.sql try to delete row but it cant

Comment: i found problem.i use bitmapimage for showing image from filetable.this class use image and downt allow to delete file